# In IE6, how can I determine if window.open is redefined?

Tags: windows, popup, internet-explorer-6

I have this odd problem with a third party script. On our site a popup window loads a demo of one of our applications when a link is clicked. The third party script is supposed to popup an additional window underneath at the same time or sometime thereafter.

(Yeah this sounds crazy but the popups must load in this way.)

Of course this works fine in FF3.

Problem is in IE6 only the third party script pops up, but not the demo popup. If I click the link again the demo popup works.

After the thirdparty script saves it's session cookie it's window doesnt popup anymore but then the Tools popup works. (if i reload the page and it saves the cookie info -- this is the expected behavior. the third party popup should only load on the first session)

Seems to me that at some point down the wire windows.open isnt getting called properly because of some timing issue or windows.open being redefined somewhere. I don't see any error messages.

To pinpoint the issue I thought I'd have to see whats going on with the windows on the click.

I guess I need some help in figuring out what information I should look for to try and debug this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll tell you if you're dealing with the real window.open or a redefined one:

```
var isOpenNative = /\[native/.test(window.open+'');
```

Comment: thanks for that!
looks like its set to true. Any idea what I should do next to test why the popup isnt launching?